# How to uninstall rightscale Rightlink

Tags: deployment, rightscale

I'm looking at using a tool such as rightscale for deployment but I don't want the machine to be managed.

How can I uninstall Rightlink at the end of a deployment?

Comment: I might be able to help you, but can you explain why you need this? You might not need RightScale at all if you don't need to manage created infrastructure.

Comment: Interested in using rightscale to create base images that can be redeployed outside of the rightscale environment.

Comment: You're talking about RightImages? As far as I know, they have nothing special in them except RightScale agents and etc. Or you want to use Server Templates? (to get installed and configured MySQL for example) for using outside RightScale?

Comment: Exactly that - Just looking to clean up the unused rightagent once it's no longer required